# Setting the PHP default encoding to UTF-8

Tags: php, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

In the "PHP Cookbook", they say (p.589) that to properly set the character encoding of outgoing data to UTF-8, it is necessary to edit the *default_encoding* configuration to *utf-8*.

However, I cannot find this configuration in file *php.ini*.  Should I simply add a line that would say `default_encoding = "utf-8"`?

I do have a *;default_charset = "iso-8859-1"*.  As you can see (`;`), right now it is not activated.  Should I remove the semicolon and set it to `"utf-8"`?  Does that take care of the default encoding?

I also found other encoding directives that I don't know what to do about:

```
[iconv]
;iconv.input_encoding = ISO-8859-1
;iconv.internal_encoding = ISO-8859-1
;iconv.output_encoding = ISO-8859-1
...
; http://php.net/exif.encode-unicode
;exif.encode_unicode = ISO-8859-15
...
;mssql.charset = "ISO-8859-1"
...
;exif.encode_unicode = ISO-8859-15
```

Is there any reason why I shouldn't simply replace them all with `utf-8`?

Comment: What is *"PHP Cookbook"*?. The book *"PHP Cookbook: Solutions and Examples for PHP Programmers"*? Or something else?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You should set your `default_charset` to UTF-8:

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
```

(*PHP Cookbook* may have a typo in it if they ask you to change the `default_encoding` — I've never heard of it.)

You'll also want to make sure that your web server is set to output UTF-8 if you're going to outputting UTF-8 encoded characters. In Apache, this can be set by in the *httpd.conf* file:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

As for modifying the  `iconv`, `exif`, and  `mssql` encoding settings, you probably don't need to set these (your settings have these commented out anyhow), but it's a good idea to change them all to UTF-8 anyhow.

Comment: For Apache, I don't have an `http.conf` file.  I use WAMPserver and they ship Apache with an `httpd.conf` file.  I suppose they're the same thing?  Also, is that a line you manually add? There's nothing about charset in my `httpd.conf` file.

Comment: that was actually a typo on my part (corrected). If you don't see a reference to `AddDefaultCharset` in the config file, you may want to look through the config included files (it will some something like `Include conf/extra/[something]`) to see if it is set in any of those. If not, just add it to the main httpd.conf file.

Comment: Is there some sort of explanation explaining what all those encoding functions do?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai - are you just asking for a general explanation of character encoding, or specifically what the listed settings control?

Comment: The listed settings. There's lots from iconv and mb_string.

Comment: no need to use AddDefaultCharset in http.conf. see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html. meta will override this.

Answer (score 10):

Modify the line

```
;default_charset = "iso-8859-1"
```

to read

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
```

About the other options, do not touch them. Avoid default settings, always explicitly set the encoding of in everything you do

- database connections,
- reading and writing files,
- converting with iconv.

Also, beware of the encoding in which your PHP files are saved, make sure that they are in UTF-8, especially if they contain strings to be displayed or compared.

Answer (score 4):

I had a problem on my MySQL query that it would not recognize some Latin accentuation, so the query would fail. I thought it could be the PHP file and so on, till I found out that using PDO to call the MySQL function I had to add the character set. The weird thing is that on the previous server I used it worked fine!

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=retirodo_main;charset=utf8';
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: @Marcos when you edited the answer i see the bold was lost, and translated to " ** " ... The asnwer should not be that text you see. Since thats the bold markdown.

Comment: Fixed, @miguel, sorry

Answer (score 2):

At the [htaccess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess) level (.htaccess file), the PHP directive should be `php_value default_charset UTF-8`.

Answer (score -3):

To resolve it, I changed "UTF-8" to "UTF-8" (without the dash), solving the problem instead.

It was on [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS).

Comment: What do you mean by "without the dash"? They look the same.