# Correctly decoding double-encoded UTF-8 on PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, encoding

So im trying to send data from an HTML page through Ajax, to a PHP page.

Thats the piece of jQuery code that im using:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        name: "João"
    }
}).done(function (data) {
    alert(data);
})
```

As you can see, the parameter im sending is "João". Before making the Ajax request jQuery encodes it on the background, "João" becomes "Jo%C3%A3o" which is double encoded UTF-8.

My problem arises when the request is sent and PHP tries to decode it on the background. **PHP decodes automatically it only once when I use $_POST, so instead of getting "João" I get "JoÃ£o".** That happens because PHP is decoding every % individually, so **%C3** becomes **Ã** and **%A3** becomes **£**.

If I try to decode it manually through utf8_decode() it will work, but im here to know if there's a better solution. What I really need is a way for PHP to decode my data correctly, even if it's double-encoded, or even triple-encoded.

Comment: That is not "double encode"... it is how UTF-8 has to be encoded. If you wish to have a single byte representing `ã`, then you need to specify a supported character set before sending the data.

Comment: Remember you don't have to repost questions as you can edit and improve the [old one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14915660/1331430). But as the other wasn't even close to a question and you've already posted a new one, you can at least delete the other.

Comment: On topic, I've never had that issue. Did you set the charset of the page to UTF-8?

Comment: Lekensteyn
I understood. My problem is that you can't change the charset before sending the Ajax data when using POST type. It will always be sent as UTF-8.

So in this case I need a way to fully decode my UTF-8 data on PHP.

Answer (score 2):

That's not double-encoded, it's correct UTF-8.  It looks like the PHP is expecting latin-1 encoding instead, and is showing you what the same bytes would mean if they were *not*
UTF-8.

In this case, since your characters seem to be below 0xFF, you could also URL-encode them first as Jo%E3o in latin-1 if you can't work out how to have PHP recognize UTF-8.

Comment: I did a test on my text editor. I wrote "João" using UTF-8 encoding, then I converted it to ANSI and the result was the exact same thing "JoÃ£o".

So it looks like that PHP is trying to decode my UTF-8 data to ANSI instead of UTF-8 itself.

Comment: So here is what is happening:
1 - The data is sent to PHP with UTF-8 encoding
2 - PHP receives it and try to decode it with a wrong encoding (ANSI).

The data HAS to be sent as UTF-8, so I need to correct the PHP part.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351694/setting-php-default-encoding-to-utf-8  you could also try the php function utf8_decode.