# How to change charset of my website to utf8?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, utf-8, character-encoding

My database communicates incorrectly with my page coded in php. First just some of the special characters displayed incorrectly, but when I applied mysqli_set_charset for my connection and default latin1 was overridden to correct utf8, my problem seemed just to change, but it wasn't solved: whenever I sent a text to database, it ended just before the first non-ASCII character. I searched more and found out that to state the encoding in a meta tag is not enough, that I must use headers. At first, I included `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` statement to the top of some of my pages. Not the texts taken from or inserted into database are correct, but on the rest of the page all special characters display like this: �

Also, having the header function called in every file is not very practical. I'm a beginner with headers, so I don't know how to apply this settings globally. I know .htaccess file can be used for this and my host claims to support it, so I started experimenting with it. I tried all the options suggested [here](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/setting-charset-in-htaccess.html), but nothing changed.

I guess both problems have the same cause: the files I get from the server are in a different charset (I don't have a proof, but the server seem to prefer latin). **So how to tell the server I want them in utf8?**

Settings as read by apache_request_headers (the important fields):

```
ACCEPT: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
ACCEPT-LANGUAGE: cs,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
ACCEPT-ENCODING: gzip, deflate
```

Only [Mozilla Web-Sniffer](http://web-sniffer.net/) sees some informations about charsets (and it varies in the languages):

```
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,UTF-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Accept-Language: de,en;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.3
```

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch ".(html|htm|js|css|php)$">
FileETag None
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
AddCharset UTF-8 .php
</ifModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Instead of "AddCharset UTF-8 .php" I used alternatives too, but nothing worked. But I'm a beginner, so there might be some mistake.

If I need something completely different, please guide me. Someone suggested [XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-xmldecl) might help, but here I'm lost even more than with the HTTP headers.

EDIT: I can't see my answer in the linked question. Yes, it guided me to php.ini, but I got only more subquestions, not answers (anything listed there don't work for me).

First, the php.ini file for my server is stored in the part of server I can't access. So I tried to create my own php.ini file in hope it will work. It consists of chunks of code I found elsewhere (I can't confess I understand it):

```
default_charset = "utf-8";
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8;

[iconv]
iconv.input_encoding = utf-8;
iconv.internal_encoding = utf-8;
iconv.output_encoding = utf-8;

exif.encode_unicode = utf-8;
```

Again, no joy here. What's wrong?

Comment: Have you added `default_charset = "utf-8";` in your php.ini?

Comment: @deceze: this helped me a lot to solve the problem on database side. But I've read it again and I didn't find any hint to the header problem I didn't already try. Perhaps I should spend an hour or two making a comprehensive list of topics I've already read and tried and make a reference list.

Comment: @deceze: well, so it was there, just I was blind. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these 2 lines on top of your .htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddCharset UTF-8 .htm .html .css .js .php
```

Also try adding this in your HTML's `<head>` section:

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried it and nothing changed :-/

Comment: Are your pages sending non utf-8 encoding headers in response?

Comment: Phpinfo() shows ISO-8859-1 wherever applicable, so if I understand it well all the headers are still in it.

Comment: Have you tried these changes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9351983/548225

Comment: Yes, though I might have used it in wrong way. See edit of my question.

Comment: I think need to figure out what is the actual source of non utf-8 encoding. Can you try adding this in your HTML's `<head>` section `<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>`

Comment: That's it! I had utf8_czech_ci there instead of utf-8, so it didn't work. Add this suggestion to your answer and I'll accept it. Thank you very much!

Comment: That's great to know. I added that to my answer.