# Weird PHP error in WordPress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, entity-relationship, lighttpd

I have a problem on a WordPress theme I am developing and I need your help.
I get a weird PHP error when I am try to move my functions in separated files.
So when I change this:

```
//file: functions.php
function function1(){
...
}
require_once('functions/other_functions.php');
```

to this:

```
//file: functions.php
require_once('functions/the_functions.php');
require_once('functions/other_functions.php');

//file: functions/the_functions.php
<?php
    function function1(){
    ...
    }
?>
```

I get an error says:

> parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in
>   functions/the_functions.php on line 1

this error stop only whith an empty file or this

```
//file: functions/the_functions.php
<?php

?>
```

The error appears only on a Linux based server with Light server and PHP 5.3.28 and works perfect on:
Windows server with Apache PHP 5.4.16, also on a Linux server with Apache and PHP 5.3.10

Comment: `function1(){` is trying to CALL function1. You'd want `function function1() { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

`function1(){` is invalid.

Perhaps you meant

```
function someFunctionName(){

}
```

Function must have a space between the function declaration and the name of the function. Otherwise it is just a rogue string.

Comment: Are you positive the editor you're using isn't inserting some foreign or unrecognized character? Are you typing or copy/pasting it in the file?

Comment: I tried both. I get a similar error in 3 files that I try to include. In one file when I insert a space character between <?php and function there is no error, but in the other files this is not working...

Comment: What encoding is the file being saved with? Ideally you'd set your editor to save with utf-8 encoding. Also, do you have access to shell? Can you create the file on the server through shell and edit it directly?

Comment: Some files were saved in ANSI encoding, I changed the encoding to utf8 without changing anything else and now the error appears almost in every file I updated.
Yes I have shell access.

Comment: At least you're seeing something now. If encoding changes replicated the error then perhaps it is a difference in the supplied encoding and the required encoding. check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351694/setting-php-default-encoding-to-utf-8 - see if following this advise helps at all. I asked about shell so you could create a new file and edit the contents directly in shell to see if the error persists from an environment that may not produce the same character errors a text editor could create.

Comment: Thanks for all your help but I am not sure that this is the problem. I I tried to restore the encoding as it was before but the errors remain. Is php using any type of caching in the files that are not modified?

Comment: not that I know of. If they work fine on another server then all that's left are environmental settings with lightserver. I don't think I know enough about that to advise

Comment: Thanks anyway for your time!