# PHP, Japanese text printing as question marks

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to print data from an array:

```
$card_list = Array(Array("Red", "あかい"), Array("Blue", "あおい"), Array("Green", "みどり"));
foreach ($card_list as $card_row)
{
  print $card_row[0] . " | " . $card_row[1] . "<br />";
}
```

However, chrome and IE. both output:

```
Red | ???
Blue | ??
Green | ???
```

Expected output is:

```
Red | あかい
Blue | あおい
Green | みどり
```

I've tried adding the following things to make it work (from past answers to similar questions) to no avail.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8'); 
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Is it possible to get this to print without escaping the input? I'd really rather not having to do that.

**As requested, here's all related code that I'm running with at the moment**

```
<?php

  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
  mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8'); 
  $card_list = Array(Array("Red", "あかい"), Array("Blue", "青い"), Array("Green", "みどり"));

?>
<html lang="ja">
  <head>  
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="flashcard_block">
    <?php
      foreach ($card_list as $card_row)
      {
          print $card_row[0] . " | " . $card_row[1] . "<br />";
      }
    ?>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Rewrite the current `<meta>` tag to: `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` and that's being properly placed within the `<head>`?

Comment: @MackieeE I had that originally, I read somewhere that it was outdated.. made no difference, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Alright =) I only ask that if it's being properly placed (As how it's currently written on the question, it ***wouldn't*** work), as that would be quite important, could you show the rest of your header html?

Comment: @MackieeE haha yes, it's not mixed in with PHP in the real one :P I updated the question with an example of what I'm using

Comment: thanks for editing! :) I've tested that same snippet and it works with Chrome, must be something simple or deeper! x) Would be interesting to find out what `mb_detect_encoding()` returns for `$card_row[1]`

Comment: You definitely don't need `mb_internal_encoding()` and what you have posted should work just peachy. Unless perhaps your php script itself is encoded in some funky character set :)

Comment: Sorry @MackieeE ! For some reason updates to this page stopped showing. 'mb_detect_encoding()' returns ASCII; I'm not sure if that's what should be showing up to be honest, but I get the same result when copy/pasting text from Wikipedia. I've tested this in Chrome and IE on my system, including the raw kernals for both without any success.

Comment: @Jack that's a really interesting point - how could I find out? I figure I'd have to manually encode it differently, right?

Comment: Here's a link to the uploaded page if that helps explain things: http://eliteshift.com/deve/EliteCards/block-flashcards.php

Comment: @Jamus What are you using to upload? Have you got ASCII Upload File-type transfer enabled maybe?

Comment: @MackieeE and Jack I think you may have solved it! Haha, thank you. I'm not sure how to change it in PHPDesigner8, but when I check in the filetype through filezilla it's ASCII. So, thank you very much! :)

Comment: @Jamus Ahh! x) Awesome! I might post an answer if that's ok - although  on a unrelated note, try out PHPStorm instead if you ever get the chance! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Possible Solutions:

#### The HTML Document

- Adding the appropriate `<meta charset="" />` or `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" />` tag for declaring the Content type for the said HTML Document.
- Setting default charset within `php.ini` (See SO's Q&A: [Setting PHP default encoding to utf-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9351983/292735))

#### The FTP/Transfer

- Making sure the Uploaded `.php` file was *not* uploaded in a manner in which could alter your characters to `???` on a un-reconsigned Unicode character.

[image]

#### At Script Writing

- The above could also happen to some IDE's or Text Editors such as Notepad++ (Below) unless you have the correct Encoding ready:

[image]

All this of course is dependant that you're not reading from the Database, this would be an extra layer into the question, although it's a golden rule to go by:

> All *layers* of the Development process must be aligned to the same Charset.

Comment: Thank you, MackieeE! Couldn't have done it without you! Such a simple error, but was beyond me haha. And I've taken your advice, my company might actually buy a commercial license should PHPStorm work well. Thanks very much ! :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think It's better to make sure what charset are the contents encoded by when they send to your browser.
If they are encoded by Shift-jis and you force the browser show it in utf-8,it will show some  strange characters.
While you know what the charset they are encoded,you can use the `mb_convert_encoding` to convert them to the charset you want.

Answer (score -1):

Place this at the beginning of the code

`mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $conn);`

Comment: Thanks Sagar, but what does this have to do with MySQL?

Comment: mysql_set_charset will Sets the client character set

Comment: @SagarPanchal As Jamus has already noted, there's **nothing** in the question that even mentions a Database. Secondly, even more so for suggesting with deprecated `mysql_*` code.