# application/json forced to have an iso-8859-1 encoding in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, content-type

Setting header to `Content-Type: application/json` I got response clearly in `iso-8859-1` in all browsers. The `default_charset` is set to `utf-8`. Adding `charset=utf-8` fixes the problem, but I don't understand why do I have to set the charset if an `application/json` default charset is `utf-8`.

Comment: Where do you set the default encoding? What is the overall architecture of your system? Please write a little more on what you are trying to do and what exactly fails.

Comment: It is set inside of `php.ini`. The overall architecture is a simple php file that sets headers and echoes `json` string.

Comment: So you have a PHP script which outputs JSON, and the charset is wrong, despite having set a default charset in php.ini, and you only get the correct charset if you specify utf8 directly in the response header?

Comment: @til_b Absolutely correct

Comment: The answer to another question http://stackoverflow.com/a/9351983/2168905 says to also check for Apache default charset, and to make sure the PHP script file itself is stored as utf8. I am guessing it is the latter (PHP script file needs to be stored in utf8).

Comment: None of that helps. Apache `AddDefaultCharset` is set to `utf-8`, PHP script is in `utf-8`.

Comment: @til_b There is no reason to point out you are out of ideas. I have already said that adding `charset=utf-8` fixes the problem. I just do not understand why do I have to add it if a charset for an `application/json` is at least redundant!