# Charset totally wrong

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

When user enters from php page to mysql it makes wierd characters like Pyr«±n«±es, ????? etc, when typing ' æøå éá etc.

I have tried anything now.

- PHP files is saved as UTF8 without bom.
- Altered all tables, database and converted to UTF8
- HTML META charset utf8
- Form has "accept-charset="utf-8"
- Right after connection: mysql_query SET NAMES UTF8
- PHP Header with charset: utf-8

What to do? When it's going to database it makes those annoying characters.

Please help me.

Comment: Can you share the offending script and the expected result?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351694/setting-php-default-encoding-to-utf-8

Comment: `SET NAMES UTF8` might not always do the trick, you might also need `mysql_set_charset('utf8')`. But this won't affect data already stored with a broken encoding. For that, you'll have to extract all the data, force it to UTF8 and then update it.

Comment: @Qirel - do not use the `mysql_*` interface; use the `mysqli_*` interface.

Comment: @Rick it's what OP used as an example ;) (with `mysql_query`) I'm well aware of its depreciation ;)