# can I change the default encoding for php or server?

Tags: php, encoding

I have a server with Windows Server 2012 R2 and a PC with Windows 8.1, both are running the same configuration of PHP and Apache and I'm using TCPDF to make a pdf, but if I use characters like Ñ, Ü, É and the likes of those I get different results on my PC and in the server is there a way to change encoding in my pc to get the same result on both?

I use this to get the right result on the server:

`mb_strtoupper($variable)`

and this for the right result on my PC:

`mb_strtoupper($variable, 'UTF-8')`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351694/setting-php-default-encoding-to-utf-8

Comment: i had the 'default_charset = "UTF-8"' line on both php.ini and no "AddDefaultCharset" on either httpd.conf, added "AddDefaultCharset UTF-8" to m pc and restarted apache, still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just restarted both, maybe the server had that config on the file but it was added after apache had been initialized