# PHP: iptcparse() and encoding

Tags: php, json, encoding, character-encoding

Using the sample image from https://www.iptc.org/std-dev/photometadata/examples/google-licensable/example-page1.html and the following code:

```
getimagesize("sample.jpg", $image_info);
if (isset($image_info["APP13"])) {
    $iptc = iptcparse($image_info["APP13"]);
    var_dump($iptc);
}
```

In the browser, the output shows this: `� Copyright 2020 IPTC (Test Images) - www.iptc.org`

That first character is supposed to be the copyright symbol. How do ensure that the special characters aren't converted into `�`?

Ultimately, the array needs to be `json_encode()`d. I believe these characters are causing problems.

**UPDATE 1:**

Per the suggestion of @6opko to use utf8_encode, I added this to my code:

```
array_walk_recursive($iptc, function (&$entry) {
    $entry = utf8_encode($entry);
});
```

This fixed the problem with the copyright symbol. However, in the index `["2#000"][0]` of `iptcparse` result, I'm getting `\u0000\u0004`. I feel this might have something to do with the IPTC specification that I do not understand yet (and it might be correct, actually). I'm investigating.

**UPDATE 2:**

Since `utf8_encode()` is deprecated, I tried adding this to my script:

`ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');`

That didn't work. I changed the implementation of the `array_walk_recursive` to use `mb_convert_encoding($entry, 'UTF-8')` -- and that also didn't work.

Comment: Is this on the browser or your command line?

Comment: I see it in my browser.

Comment: Can you do utf8_encode()?

Comment: Most likely it is a display problem than the content of the metadata inside the image being the culprit. Adding a `<meta charset="utf-8">` should fix the issue. It is anyways just an `&copy;` thing.

Comment: @nice_dev: I thought so too, so I tested it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Strange. Will try it on my machine as well then.

Comment: @nice_dev And the image is not corrupt because it shows correctly [here](https://getpmd.iptc.org/getpmd/html/isearch1/ipmd/?imgurl=https://www.iptc.org/std-dev/photometadata/examples/google-licensable/images/IPTC-GoogleImgSrcPmd_testimg01.jpg).

Comment: @nice_dev - I've tried calling `header('content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8');` before outputting anything. Problem exist. I don't want to assume that this probablem is exclusively `&copy;` thing.

Comment: @6opko - `utf8_encode()` fixed the copyright symbol issue (I had to do an `array_walk_recursive`). It didn't fix everything, though. There are still some weird encoded characters. Will update the original post.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie Change the default encoding then. By default it is ISO-8859-1. [See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351694/setting-the-php-default-encoding-to-utf-8) . Relying on `utf8_encode` isn't a good idea as mentioned in the warning section in the [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware It was apparently an encoding format issue from PHP's end.

Comment: @nice_dev - I tried setting `ini_set( 'default_charset', 'UTF-8' );` in my code and removed the use of `utf8_encode()`. I'm back to my original problem. How can I get rid of the deprecated function? I tried `mb_convert_encoding`, and that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it is an encoding issue since PHP uses `ISO-8859-1` format by default. For newer versions, it is already `UTF-8`. For older ones, [see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351694/setting-the-php-default-encoding-to-utf-8) to change the default settings.

[`utf8_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) is a viable option but will get deprecated in the newer PHP versions.

So, it is best to use [`mb_convert_encoding`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) to convert a string from one character encoding to another.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

getimagesize("sample.jpg", $image_info);
if (isset($image_info["APP13"])) {
    $iptc = iptcparse($image_info["APP13"]);
    echo mb_convert_encoding($iptc['2#116'][0], "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1");
}
```